# Highcharter position dodge for scatter plots

Tags: r, highcharts

I would like to overlay two series of scatter plot on top of a bar plot. In ggplot, I could do it easily using `position = "dodged"` but I am unable to find any similar in Highcharter.

Below is what I want to achieve:

```
test <- data.frame(year = c("2019","2020"), exposure = c(1000,1500), bycount = c(1100,900), byamt = c(1000,800))
   

ggplot(data = test) + geom_bar(data = test, aes(x = year,y = exposure), stat = "identity")+
 geom_point(data = data.table(pivot_longer(test,cols = c("bycount","byamt"))), 
 aes(x =year,y = value, group = name, colour = name, shape = name), 
 size = 5, fill = "white", position = position_dodge(width = 1)) + 
 scale_colour_manual(values = c("red","blue"),labels = c("By Amount","By Count")) + 
 scale_shape_manual(values = c(21,22), labels = c("By Amount", "By Count"))
```

[image: https://ibb.co/8ggDBgV]

Comment: Hi! Are you looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jgs5m01p/

Comment: Effectively, but my x values need to be automatically populated.

Comment: There is no such option in Highcharts like in ggplot. You need to set either x values or series.pointPlacement like here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p4eowutk/